# How do I make a really flavorful turkey burger?

Tags: grilling, turkey, seasoning, hamburgers

Since turkey burgers don't have a lot of fat, you lose a lot of the flavor that you get with beef.  Also, you have to make sure you cook them through (170 degrees), so they tend to dry out.

What are your pro tips for cooking great turkey burgers?

- Preparation
- Seasoning
- **Grilling techniques** (high heat? tin foil?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have been eating turkey burgers for years.  The super secret is to not let them dry out while cooling.  I take a pound of ground turkey, mixed 2 tablespoons of Worcestershire sauce, 1/2 teaspoon salt, 2 shakes garlic powder and 1/2 teaspoon of water.  Then mix thoroughly by hand.  After patty-ing them to 1/4 inch thick patties, I grill for about 5-6 minutes per side, turning a quarter turn at 2-3 minutes.  After removing from grill, I wrap in foil and let sit for 5-10 minutes.   Voila!

Comment: Do you use high, direct heat?

Comment: On the stove, medium, to medium-high.  Grill medium-high.

Answer (score 7):

I found [this article](http://aht.seriouseats.com/archives/2009/11/the-burger-lab-turkey-burgers-that-dont-suck.html) really interesting. It covers a chef's attempts to make a turkey burger taste good.

The recommendation is to puree some eggplant with it (to improve the moisture level), and add soy sauce, marmite and anchovies to make it taste good.

Answer (score 2):

I really like adding lime to turkey burgers, usually with salt and pepper.  It helps keep them moist and adds a nice, fresh flavor.

One of my favorite turkey burgers is Rachel Ray's Turkey Loco Burgers -- http://www.rachaelray.com/recipe.php?recipe_id=1315

Also, her spanakopita burgers with spinach and feta are great.  (I can't post the link, but switch the recipe_id to 155 on the above link).

Answer (score 2):

We have found adding a little ricotta cheese and oil to the mixture helps to keep is moist and soft.  Then add other seasonings per your tastes (garlic powder, salt, pepper, etc.)

It makes it a little harder for grilling since it is even softer than normal, just used a cross hatch grill thing (same for fish) and it will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

my recipe:

- Ground turkey
- Porccini mushrooms
- salt + pepper
- cayenne
- a dash of Worcestershire sauce
- a bit of grated Gouda
- juice of two tomatoes
- a splash of lime juice

Method:

- Mix them up really well ( I usually mix them in a dough mixer for 10 to 20 minutes)
- If i'm grilling them I usually put a stalk of rosemary on top of the burger.
- If i'm eating them at home, I usually pan fry them in garlic infused oil

Answer (score 1):

My recipe comes a little from my middle eastern background, but I always get compliments:
(Based on 2 pounds of ground turkey, no measurements, do it to taste)

- Fresh minced parsley
- Salt
- White pepper
- Finely minced garlic
- Grated onion (usually half or more)
- 1 egg (start with one at least, add
  another if it still feels too 'dry'
  with the bread crumbs)
- Bread crumbs (I usually use Progresso
  Plain, but Italian works fine too)
- Worcestershire

A note: I use this same recipe for beef burgers too but I put a lot MORE spices and bread crumbs in the in the turkey burger recipe.

Comment: Pesto (basil, garlic, olive oil, parmesan, small nuts) works well in place of plain garlic. Oddly, summer Savory also makes a tasty addition.

Answer (score 1):

My Mom makes the most fantastic turkey burgers. Her secret is [Lipton Onion Soup Mix](http://thesouthinmymouth.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/lipton.jpg).

The only other added ingredient was cayenne pepper.

She wouldn't add salt because the soup mix has plenty.

Once the burger is cooked (she pan fries them), she deglazes the pan with a bit of water and then "bastes" the burgers with the pan drippings. Then she melts a slice of provolone cheese on top and serves the burger on a buttered, toasted Kaiser roll with thinly-sliced onion, lettuce, and honey-dijon mustard.

If you don't like the ingredients in the soup mix (it has MSG and a couple of disodiums), try this: http://www.food.com/recipe/copycat-liptons-onion-soup-mix-24952

I rather suspect it's the MSG and disodiums (all of which are recognized as safe for consumption, but demonized by foodies everywhere) that make them taste so great.

Answer (score 1):

Add umami! Soy Sauce, miso, and finely chopped mushrooms add a lot of meaty flavor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fond of chopping the green of a green onion into 1/2" lengths and adding that in. Gives it a really great flavour that matches well with cumin, if that's your thing!