# Keep or remove skin when grinding poultry?

Tags: chicken, meat, fat, turkey, grinding

After reading [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1419/how-do-i-make-a-really-flavorful-turkey-burger) I made "burgers" with ground chicken thigh. (Didn't have turkey thighs handy.) I have the feeling chicken thighs have plenty of fat, so less likely to dry out than turkey, but it occurred to me: what are the pros and cons to removing skin before grinding poultry meat? Especially if the complaint of turkey "burgers" is that they are too dry and lack flavor, wouldn't the skin help with that?

Comment: By the way, ground chicken thigh with skin, plus garlic and anchovy paste, makes a fine patty. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you hit the nail on the head when you mentioned fat.  Leaving the skin will give your ground poultry a higher percentage of fat content, resulting a more tender and moist "burger".